# How to fix malloc(): memory corruption in JVM

Tags: ubuntu, memory, java, docker

Occasionally, my JVMs crash because of memory corruption.
Whenever I run into this error, stopping all Docker containers makes the JVMs work again. Restarting the Docker service also makes the problem go away for a while.

```
*** Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007fdd6404af00 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fdd7e3ff7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8213e)[0x7fdd7e40a13e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x54)[0x7fdd7e40c184]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(+0x5ab2)[0x7fdd6867dab2]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(+0x6378)[0x7fdd6867e378]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getByInetAddress0+0x40)[0x7fdd6867e560]
[0x7fdd7417bbd1]
```

I need a pointer how to approach this problem. I don't see how to use the memory map dumped as part of the error message to pinpoint the problem:

```
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18876286                           /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 18876286                           /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
011c0000-011e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
bc600000-bdac0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bdac0000-c1800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
c1800000-d12c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64).

Comment: Have you tried running a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Memory corruption is a programming error that should not happen. You are not supposed to do explicit memory allocation and management (malloc/free in C) in Java, the JVM takes care of all this for you.

Therefore, unless you have added some custom (native) libraries to your Java environment, the problem lies with the JVM itself and you should fill a bug report where appropriate (https://launchpad.net/ if your JVM is the one distributed with Ubuntu).